# ansible looping through the result and finding files

Tags: ansible, file-globs

I am using ansible to configire 10-20 linux systems. I have a set of tools that I define in my invetory files with versions, as:

```
tools:
  - tool: ABC
    version: 7.8
  - tool: XYZ
    version: 8.32.1
```

Now, in my playback yml file, I would like to loop through them and have the necessay installation logic. Such as:

DEBUG tools loop

```
  - name: Find installer files
    copy:
      src=
    with_items:
    - "{{ tools }}"
    when:
      tools.tool == "ABC"
```

In my case,  {{tools.tool}}/{{tools.version}} has a tgz file which I need to unarchive at a remote location. Do you know how to do this? I have tried these:

```
- name: Find installer files
    vars:
      files: {{ lookup("fileglob",'tools/{{item.tool}}/linux/{{item.version}}/*') }}
    unarchive:
      src: "{{ files }}"
      dest: "tools/{{item.tool}}/{{item.version}}/"
    with_items:
    - "{{ tools }}"
    when:
      item.tool == "ABC"

- name: Find installer files
   debug:
     msg: "{{ item}}"
   with_items:
   - "{{ tools }}"
   with_fileglob:
   - "tools/{{item.tool}}/linux/{{item.version}}/*"
   when:
     item.toolchain == "ABC"
```

But none worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that simple as Your own solution breaks if there are multiple files in the directory, I assume.
So if You only have one file in the directory I wouldn't use `fileglob` at all but define a fixed name for it that You can generate knowing tool and version.

I also see the need for such sort of things often but did not found any nice solution for that. Only such ugly thing as:

```
- name: example book
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    tools:
      - tool: ABC
        version: 7.8
      - tool: XYZ
        version: 8.32.1
    tools_files: []
  tasks:
    - name: prepare facts
      set_fact:
        tools_files: "{{ tools_files + [{'tool': item.tool | string, 'version': item.version | string, 'files': lookup('fileglob', 'tools/' ~ item.tool ~ '/linux/' ~ item.version ~ '/*', wantlist=True)}] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ tools }}"
    - name: action loop
      debug:
        msg: "{{ {'src': item[1], 'dest': 'tools/' ~ item[0].tool ~ '/' ~ item[0].version ~ '/'} }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ tools_files }}"
        - files
      when:
        item[0].tool == "ABC"
```

or

```
- name: example book
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    tools:
      - tool: ABC
        version: 7.8
      - tool: XYZ
        version: 8.32.1
    tools_files: []
  tasks:
    - name: prepare facts
      set_fact:
        tools_files: "{{ tools_files + [{'tool': item.tool | string, 'version': item.version | string, 'files': lookup('fileglob', 'tools/' ~ item.tool ~ '/linux/' ~ item.version ~ '/*', wantlist=True)}] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ tools }}"
    - name: action loop
      debug:
        msg: "{{ {'src': item[1], 'dest': 'tools/' ~ item[0].tool ~ '/' ~ item[0].version ~ '/'} }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ tools_files | subelements('files') }}"
      when:
        item[0].tool == "ABC"
```

Maybe I miss somthing because such things are a very basic feature (looping throug an array generating a result array beeing able to use all functions available and not just `map` using `filters` where some important things are just not available or cannot be used because map gives the inport as first argument to filter always).

Comment: Thanks. I found looping in ansible as extremely difficult task. I guess for some people coding is much more easier than declarative style.

Comment: Yes indeed. And not only looping but also other stuff that makes the plays flexible and thus generic/reusable often require multiple blocks of declaration instead if just two line codes for each action.

Answer (score 1):

That was actually simple. This worked for me:

```
- name: Find installer files
  unarchive:
    src: 
    "lookup('fileglob','tools/item.tool/linux/item.version/*') }}"
    dest: "tools/{{item.tool}}/{{item.version}}/"
    with_items:
    - "{{ tools }}"
    when:
      item.tool == "ABC"
```